# Repair NTFS Partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, partition-recovery

I have an external drive that recently became unreadable. When I run chkdsk I get the following:

The type of the file system is NTFS.
The First NTFS Boot Sector is Unreadable or Corrupt
Reading second NTFS boot sector instead.
The First NTFS Boot Sector is Unreadable or Corrupt
Reading second NTFS boot sector instead.
Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKSDK aborted.

I've tried various file recovery utilities (such as R-Studio and EaseUS). Each utility has been able to recover some, but not all of the files. However, the files recovered by each utility are a different subset of the files on the disk leading me to believe that none of the scans are truly comprehensive.

What I'd really like to do is repair the NTFS boot sector if possible. My hope is that will allow me to open the volume and explore its contents. Any advice for the best way to do this?

Comment: I just noticed something interesting from an R-Studio scan: It found a NTFS boot sector at the very end of the volume. Could this be the backup boot sector? How can I restore it?

Comment: Is the *only* issue that it's not bootable? If so, have you tried running another OS, e.g. a Linux live distro, from USB, and then mounting the HDD?

Comment: I am having same problem, i am now considering pluggin the drive to differrent computer/OS, i already used Minitool partition recovery and its Data (not partition) recovery module, though it is very slow, and hard to find raw useable files in it, all properly named ones was broken. Next try is to quick format the drive and try Recuva software (likely will not work and files will be deleted for good).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and tried several things and two recovery software (MiniTool and EaseUs) and only EaseUs Data Recovery Wizard (search hash: 4E4A8F12443DC9A6D9456E81348D7B3A7EF45310 ) was able to recover non-damaged files in my case. I only wish i know about the way to repair the partition itself without need to format and copy all the data from backups.